# Строковые цифры и как их перевести в число

Tags: php, utf-8

Здравствуйте, вот попались такие цифры "１４" т.е это символы которые изображают числа.

```
print_r((int)'１４'); // 0
```

Как бы такие символы форматнуть в число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `mb_convert_kana` с параметром преобразования чисел `n`:

```
echo (int) mb_convert_kana('１４', 'n'); //14
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-kana.php

Answer (score -1):

Можно для начала заменить пробелы на пустую строку, а потом привести к `int`. 
Например: `(int) str_replace(' ', '', '1 4').`

Comment: Проблема в том, что там нет пробелов. Это символы такие...